# What does value = (null) means?

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth, characteristics

```
<CBService: 0x1702622c0 Peripheral = <CBPeripheral: 0x1780bc680 identifier = 17D7A5C8-BAB5-82E6-826E-BE80A994687A, Name = "Bluegiga CR Demo", state = connected>, Primary = YES, UUID = 0BD51666-E7CB-469B-8E4D-2742F1BA77CC>

Notification began on <CBCharacteristic: 0x170086e50 UUID = E7ADD780-B042-4876-AAE1-112855353CC1, Value = (null), Properties = 0x28, Notifying = YES, Broadcasting = NO>
```

What does value = (null) means? I can't use writeValue? I need to use updateValue?

Comment: It means that the entity called "value" is `nil`, as in never been set (or set with a `nil` value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CBCharacteristic` has several `@properties`... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/translated_content/CBCharacteristic.html

One is called `value` which is of type `NSData`.

If this is null it means there is no data in it. It hasn't been instantiated.

Comment: OK and why i can't writeValue? and after this it shouldn't be null right?

Comment: how can i change this?

Comment: @mond well, I've never used this class before but I guess it is set by the type of characteristic. The property is read-only so you won't be able to change it yourself. From the docs... value
The value of the characteristic. (read-only)

@property(retain, readonly) NSData *value
Discussion
This property contains the value of the characteristic. For example, a temperature measurement characteristic of a health thermometer service may have a value that indicates a temperature in Celsius.

Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared In
CBCharacteristic.h